# How to disable a whole drop-down menu on Electron?

Tags: menu, electron, menubar

I am developing a desktop application with [**Electron**](https://electronjs.org/). I have added some items to the [**menu bar**](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu).

Sometimes I open some modal forms with bootstrap in the program. When these popups are open I want to disable the menu items.

I have made some research and some people says that the [menu bar could be removed](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-disable-the-default-menubar/17722/12). But I do not want to create my own HTML menu.

And there is another option, maybe the best approach. Disabling all the options of each dropdown menu. Each menuitem has an [`enabled` attribute](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item), so it can be changed in runtime.

[image]

Is there way to avoid dropping down the menu and disable the drop-down menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic menus are [not currently supported](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/528). This has something to do with the fact that the menus in Electron use the Chromium menu code which has no dynamic features.

When your File menu is empty, you could replace the entire menu with one that does not have the File menu in it?

Comment: Well then I'll have to resign myself to doing that. I think that replace the entire menu is good enough. Anyway I will be awaiting any progress in that functionality. Thank you